# Looping is right but does not give right numbering. What's wrong with these codes?

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to display the exam questions numbering in my status bar so I do it like this,

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['question']); $i++){
    $user=addslashes($_POST['user'][$i]);
    $question=addslashes($_POST['question'][$i]);
    $optA=addslashes($_POST['optA'][$i]);
    $optB=addslashes($_POST['optB'][$i]);
    $optC=addslashes($_POST['optC'][$i]);
    $optD=addslashes($_POST['optD'][$i]);
    $correct=addslashes($_POST['correct'][$i]);
    $qtype=addslashes($_POST['qtype'][$i]);
    $category=addslashes($_POST['category'][$i]);
    $numbering=$i;

    if($correct!=NULL){
    $insert="insert into tbl_randomq(username, question, optA, optB, optC, optD, correct, qtype, category, numbering) values('$user','$question','$optA','$optB','$optC','$optD','$correct', '$qtype', '$category', $numbering);";
    $insertrs=mysqli_query($con,$insert);
}
    }
```

With these, the expected results for $numbering would be, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9..so on, but the result set appeared like 1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10...

Why is it 6 and 7 do not appear??? :( it ruins the system. Help with these please. Did I missed some parameters or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is it 6 and 7 do not appear?

Because `if($correct!=NULL)` is returning `false`. This means that `$_POST['correct'][$i]` is either not set or is being type-casted to a value that will equal null. You will want to inspect the submitted post data to verift dat for 6 and 7 are being correctly submitted.

Regarding type-casting/juggling:

```
$a = null;
echo $a == null; // true
echo $a === null; // true


$a = 0;
echo $a == null; // true
echo $a === null; // false

$a = '';
echo $a == null; // true
echo $a === null; // false
```

Check out [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) for more information on how PHP type juggles.

Comment: i checked my data sir, all my data have value for $correct, and my questions are generated randomly, why is it, always 6 and 7 are the missing numbers?

Comment: Please include your data in the question. Also pay special attention to type-juggling.

Comment: Sir, what can say about: expected results are, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 but returns, 1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10,11,12. If it has problem regarding type-juggling presumably the answer be like 1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10 ???

Comment: When I changed the value of $numbering=$i to $numbering=$i++, the results were 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20--

Comment: Posting the submitted data, i.e., `$_POST` will help find the problem (the code is the same for each `question`. Therefore, the difference will only be found in the submitted data).

Comment: YES SIR! I OVERLOOKED MY DATA! You're right 6 and 7 are actually null. :) I didnt realized that I made it as a hidden field if the $correct is equals to null, that's why it doesnt appear to be null in my table! THANKS ALOT!